# rvm how turn it on always when we open terminal in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, ruby, make

I am new user of 13.10 ubuntu I am facing one problem when want to install rvm, even though it is already install and using it on virtualt box. 
Problem is that when i start terminal and put to check my RVM is working or not with this??

than i try to change
Put this in your `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`:

```
# This loads RVM into a shell session.
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

but again when close terminal and try to check rvm is working or not its say
when i try `$type rvm | head -1` and also try to check with `$type rvm | head -n 1`

but rails not working showes after i found another site that below code its start work

```
user$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

and than check rvm status it is started, `$type rvm | head -1`
"rvm is a funcation" working correctly but when i closed and open it next time its not working again

than i put

```
$ echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

and close terminal again start but not rvm start automatically with terminal start
if i use this code its work

```
user$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

my questions is that how much rvm is importnat to work with terminal start when we want to do work on ruby??
how we can run rvm open dirctlly with out `user$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` in terminal??I mean when we start our terminal RVM will start autmatically??
what is the role of RVM in rails project if we have install already rail is it neccessary rvm will work with it??

Answer (score 0):

Loading rvm with the shell is for... usability/convenience.

Where are you loading rvm in your bash_profile? iirc, it should be loaded at the end.

If you're having trouble with this I can recommend using rbenv (having used both and getting much less of a head ache with rbenv)

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Why-rbenv%3F